# how to install VIM + Vuddle on msys2

Tags: vim, msys2

Vim came as default on my msys2 version but I don't see the ~/.vimrc file nor ~/.vim/ directory

any thoughts

---

Comment: Manually create them if they aren't there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just place a file in /etc/vimrc

```
    " An example for a vimrc file.
    "
    " Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
    " Last change:  2011 Apr 15
    "
    " To use it, copy it to
    "     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
    "         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
    "  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
    "       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

    " When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
    if v:progname =~? "evim"
      finish
    endif

    " Use Vim settings, rather than Vi settings (much better!).
    " This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
    set nocompatible

    " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
    set backspace=indent,eol,start

    if has("vms")
      set nobackup      " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
    else
      set backup        " keep a backup file
    endif
    set history=50      " keep 50 lines of command line history
    set ruler       " show the cursor position all the time
    set showcmd     " display incomplete commands
    set incsearch       " do incremental searching

    " For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
    " let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

    " Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
    map Q gq

    " CTRL-U in insert mode deletes a lot.  Use CTRL-G u to first break undo,
    " so that you can undo CTRL-U after inserting a line break.
    inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>

    " In many terminal emulators the mouse works just fine, thus enable it.
    if has('mouse')
      set mouse=a
    endif

    " Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
    " Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
    if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
      syntax on
      set hlsearch
    endif

    " Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
    if has("autocmd")

      " Enable file type detection.
      " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
      " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
      " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
      filetype plugin indent on

      " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
      augroup vimrcEx
      au!

      " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
      autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

      " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
      " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
      " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
      " Also don't do it when the mark is in the first line, that is the default
      " position when opening a file.
      autocmd BufReadPost *
        \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
        \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
        \ endif

      augroup END

    else

      set autoindent        " always set autoindenting on

    endif " has("autocmd")

    " Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
    " file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
    " Only define it when not defined already.
    if !exists(":DiffOrig")
      command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
              \ | wincmd p | diffthis
    endif
```